# adjective "unconscious" after verb "spend" - spend most of that unconscious

Tags: adjectives

I saw this sentence in a test passage.

> Koalas rest sixteen to eighteen hours a day and spend most of that unconscious.

Why is "unconscious" used in the sentence above instead of "unconsciously"? It seems that "unconsciously" would be more appropriate because it modifies "spend".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unconscious (adjective) has two meanings: 1 not awake 2 (of people) not perceived at the level of awareness. An unconscious action is something you do without thinking about it. Only this second meaning has the adverb 'unconsciously'. The koalas spend most of their resting time asleep (being unconscious, adjective, meaning 1).

[Unconscious](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unconscious)

[Unconsciously](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unconsciously)

Comment: In other words, it's being used as an adjective rather than an adverb.

Comment: Then, can the sentence above be changed to "spend most of that being unconscious"?

Comment: Yes, it can be changed to that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.